# how to not add null values from database

Tags: .net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, combobox

I am populating a comboBox from a database through the use of its propery - `Use Data Bound Items`
Instead of making another table, I just added another 2 Columns in MainTable.
they should be `DVRID` and `DVRIP`
then I populated my `comboDVR` from `DVRID` and I get `DVR16F` & `DVR14F` on my dropdown and their `selectedValues` are from `DVRIP` which is their own ip addresses.
I typically get what I want, only problem is, since I populated my `comboDVR` from a column, it gets all items in that column even the null ones..
[image]
so when I dropdown, its too long.. and if a user click on a blank item, throws and exception.
is there a way that I can remove or not get null values from DRVID column? or do I need to create a separate table for that?

**btw** I do this because my boss said he does not want the client to manually input the dvr's ip address so he wants a dropdown menu of the dvrs' names instead.

Comment: Can you provide the SQL query you use?

Comment: just did select * from mytable.. though I am not using hard code to connect my combobox, anyway, I just created another table thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change your SELECT query to filter out the rows where `DVRID` is NULL, like this:

```
SELECT ID, MarkerName, Latitude, Longitude, CameraID, DVR, HostAddress, DVRID, DVRIP 
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
WHERE DVRID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, I have found my solution, I just created a new table for that DVR items. will not delete this for others having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your `select` statement is returning null values from your DVR column, you could use this:

```
isnull(DVR, '')
```

so it returns an empty string.  Then in your code behind you could do something like this:

```
while(dr.read()) {
     if(dr["DVR"].ToString() == String.Empty)
          continue;
     else
        yourControl.Items.Add(new ListItem("your text", "your value"));
}
```

I hope this points you to the right direction.